# Adding a new version manually for updating a software

Tags: clickonce

I have a software that I don't have access to its sources. Now I want to add some DLL files for updating the software. I don't know how I can add folder to update the path so that the software recognizes that there is a new version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're asking, but you can try a DLL Injector or edit with ASM to inject a DLL.

Comment: In the path of updating software, there are some folders that each of them contains DLLs for updating. For example: AppName_2345345bdf_0002.0004_234234sdd33b. I want to add a new folder with my DLLs so that Clickonce recognizes that a new version is created.